Moving camera FOV between a min and max value
I need a code that move camera field of view (FOV) between a min and max value like 50-70 to zoom in and zoom out the camera view
For that i tried Mathf.MoveTowards function and it works well :
GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = Mathf.MoveTowards(camFOV,maxFOV,speed*Time.deltaTime)
Now i need this to run like that :
1)First wait 2 to 5 seconds
2)Zoom in (decrease fov to minFOV)
3)Wait 1 to 3 seconds randomly
4)Zoom out (increase fov to maxFOV)
5)REAPET THIS PROCESS UNTIL GAME RUNS
Please help me!
Thanks.

This type of "do X, wait, do Y, wait" problem is a great use for Coroutines. In your specific case, it would look something like:
IEnumerator ChangeCameraFOV(Camera camera) {
  while (true) { // Or until some condition

    // Wait 2-5 seconds (random)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2f, 5f));

    // Zoom in
    while (camera.fieldOfView > minFOV) {
      camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.MoveTowards(camera.fieldOfView, minFOV, speed * Time.deltaTime);
      yield return null; // Wait for next frame
    }
    
    // Wait 1-3 seconds (random)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, 3f));


    // Zoom out
    while (camera.fieldOfView < maxFOV) {
      camera.fieldOfView = Mathf.MoveTowards(camera.fieldOfView, maxFOV, speed * Time.deltaTime);
      yield return null; // Wait for next frame
    }
  }
}

And then start the coroutine with StartCoroutine:
Corotuine cameraChangeCoroutine;
public void Start() {
  cameraChangeCoroutine = StartCoroutine(ChangeCameraFOV(GetComponent<Camera>()));
}

And stop it with StopCoroutine:
StopCoroutine(cameraChangeCoroutine);


Imagine camera fov is 60 and minFov is 50 and maxFov is 80, in this condition both while loops conditions are true and both whiles run, this will not work :)

Coroutines don't work that way. yield return new WaitForSeconds is blocking, the rest of the code gets paused until that completes, and it executes top-down in order. Did you try it?

yes, when i set speed of mathf.movetowards to a small number like 5 or 10 fov starts to deceasing and increasing quickly but in a short range, but when i set speed to a larger number like 200 this will happens : https://uploadnow.io/f/RBBqWwr

I can't replicate this, you're only ever starting the coroutine once, correct? (not in Update()?)    Try changing out the > minFOV and < maxFOV for for != minFOV and != maxFOV. if that still doesn't work, [edit] your code into your question

its solved! thank you :)
